# variables en Select dentro de Stored Procedure no funcionan

Tags: mysql

Estoy con este problema

```
  DECLARE Registros tinyint DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE Final TinyInt DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE CP CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_NAME=@Tabla AND COLUMN_NAME=@Campo;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Final=1;

  SET Final=0; 
  SET @Tabla=_NombreTabla;
  SET @Campo=_NombreCampo;

  OPEN CP;

  WHILE Final=0 DO
      FETCH CP INTO Registros; 
    IF Final=0 THEN
         CLOSE CP;
         RETURN 1;          
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE CP;
  RETURN 0;
```

Siempre se va por el Handler de Fin de Cursor

El Stored recibe ambos parámetros de entrada

```
`_NombreTabla` VARCHAR(80),
`_NombreCampo` VARCHAR(80)
```

Si corro la consulta SQL a mano, funciona perfecto y me trae 1 registro, indicando que la tabla y el campo existen.

Pero al correr la sentencia con las variables de reemplazo @Tabla y @Campo no funcionan.

A pesar de que depurando el Stored con dbForge Studio, las variables muestran que tienen los valores correctos asignados como parámetros de entrada.

Que puede estar mal ? en definitiva intento crear una función que reciba el nombre de tabla y campo y devuelva 1 o 0 si existe dicho campo o no.

Gracias !

Comment: Qué valores tiene @Tabla y @Campo antes del set? Los `set` no deberían ir antes del select?

Comment: Nunca te deja meter un SET antes de un DECLARE